# How can I simplify $\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \int_0^n e^{-x} \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \, dx$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, simplifying-expressions, integral-equations

How can I simplify $\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \int_0^n e^{-x} \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \, dx$ ?

```
Limit[Integrate[(1 - x/n)^n/E^x, 
   {x, 0, n}], n -> Infinity]
```

The result was

Limit[ConditionalExpression[$\left.e^{-n} (-n)^{-n} (\Gamma (n+1,-n)-\Gamma (n+1)),\Re(n)>0\land \Im(n)=0\right],n\to \infty]$

```
Limit[ConditionalExpression[
   (-Gamma[1 + n] + Gamma[1 + n, 
      -n])/(E^n*(-n)^n), 
   Re[n] > 0 && Im[n] == 0], 
  n -> Infinity]
```

was supposed to be $1$ since

$\int_0^{\infty } e^{-x} \, dx=1$

```
Integrate[E^(-x), {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

I did try Simplify and Reduce but neither work.

Thank you in advance

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: What happens if you use `Assumptions`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I edited my question

Comment: @MichaelE2 `Refine[E^-n (-n)^-n (-Gamma[1 + n] + Gamma[1 + n, -n]), 
 Assumptions -> n -> \[Infinity]]` does nothing, returns the same `E^-n (-n)^-n (-Gamma[1 + n] + Gamma[1 + n, -n])`

Comment: Shouldn't the limit be the integral of $e^{-2x}$ instead of $e^{-x}$? i.e., 1/2? Have you tried [`DiscreteLimit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteLimit.html)?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform After writing `DiscreteLimit[...]` you got $e^{-2x}$ ? I did it and returned the same expression

Comment: For large $n$ the integral is $\frac12 - \frac{1}{8n} - \frac{1}{32 n^2} + \frac{1}{128 n^3}+O(n^{-4})$. I don't know how to get there in *Mathematica* though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$(1-\frac{x}{n})^n$ may be approximated by $exp(-\frac{x}{n})^n$

```
Exp[-1/n x] // Series[#, {x, 0, 3}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Limit[Exp[-1/n x]^n - (1 - x/n)^n, n -> Infinity]
```

=>

> 0

```
Limit[Integrate[Exp[-x]*Exp[-1/n x]^n, {x, 0, n}], n -> Infinity]
```

=>

> 1/2

---

#### About the error

```
Table[Exp[-1/n x]^n - (1 - x/n)^n, {n, 500, 10000, 500}] // 
 Plot[#, {x, 0, 100}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Your addition "About the error" is not good: the range of the integration is $[0,n]$ and the maximum value is reached around $x=2$ up to the results of Table[Maximize[{Exp[-1/n x]^n - (1 - x/n)^n, x >= 0 && x <= n}, 
   x], {n, 10, 110, 20}];N[%] $$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0.0280001 & \{x\to 1.931\} \\
 0.00912372 & \{x\to 1.97753\} \\
 0.00544974 & \{x\to 1.98658\} \\
 0.00388522 & \{x\to 1.99043\} \\
 0.00301863 & \{x\to 1.99257\} \\
 0.00246812 & \{x\to 1.99392\} \\
\end{array}
\right). $$

Comment: @user64494 "not good" is not a clear statement. It is even more confusing as your example clearly shows that the error decreases with n and what matters is n->Infinity. Maybe I missed your point, but you were previously asked to elaborate and decided to just repost it
.

Answer (score 6):

You can move the limit inside the integral (please see Rudin, **Principles of Mathematical Analysis**, Third Edition, *Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem*, p. 321):

```
Limit[Integrate[Exp[-x] Limit[(1 - x/n)^n, n -> \[Infinity]],
      {x, 0, n}], n -> \[Infinity]]
```

Answer:

```
 1/2
```

As you surely know, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^{-x}$$

So the integral becomes

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-2x} dx=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95370/discussion-on-answer-by-mjw-how-can-i-simplify-lim-n-to-infty-int-0n).

Answer (score 5):

Workaround:

We have a function`E^(-a*x) (1 - x/n)^n` where `a=1` then:

```
func=E^(-a*x) (1 - x/n)^n;
sol1 = InverseLaplaceTransform[func, a, s]
(*(1 - x/n)^n DiracDelta[s - x]*)
sol2 = Integrate[sol1, {x, 0, n}, Assumptions -> {s > 0, n < Infinity}]
(*(1 - s/n)^n (DiscreteDelta[n] + HeavisideTheta[n - s] - HeavisideTheta[-n, n - s])*)
sol3 = Limit[sol2, n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> s > 0]
(*E^-s*)
sol4 = LaplaceTransform[sol3, s, a]
(*1/(1 + a)*)
Limit[sol4, a -> 1]
(*1/2*)
```

By numerics:

```
f[n_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(1 - x/n)^n*E^(-x), {x, 0, n}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"];
Table[f[10^n], {n, 0, 6}]
(*{0.367879, 0.487198, 0.498747, 0.499875, 0.499987, 0.499999, 0.5} *)
```

Answer  is `1/2` not `1`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95304/discussion-on-answer-by-mariusz-iwaniuk-how-can-i-simplify-lim-n-to-infty).

Comment: Thank you @Kuba (and apologies to everyone who made inoffensive comments in various parts of this thread).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is not entirely correct to approximate $\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ as $e^{-x}$ because even though $n$ goes to infinity, the integration probes the region $x\sim n$, hence there are contributions in the integral for which $\frac{x}{n}$ is not arbitrarily small!

Of course $e^{-x}$ suppresses all such contributions; nonetheless, IMHO it is not warranted to *apply the limit inside the integral*.

Let us instead consider the following. With the change of variables $x=n a$, we have $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{n}e^{-x}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^ndx=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{1}ne^{-na}\left(1-a\right)^nda=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{1}ne^{-na}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^ka^k\binom{n}{k}da$$
Note that the Taylor expansion behaves well for all integration region as $0<a<1$. Thus
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{n}e^{-x}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^ndx=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\binom{n}{k}\int\limits_{0}^{1}e^{-na}a^kda$$

We can do the integration (e.g. with Mathematica) to find
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{n}e^{-x}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^ndx=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^{-k}\binom{n}{k}\left(k!-\Gamma(k+1,n)\right)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k$$

Therefore, **the limit does not exist!** (Thanks to @user64494 for pointing out my typo) However, we can always get the regularized result (a.k.a do analytical continuation from the region it does exist):

```
Sum[(-1)^k, {k, 0, \[Infinity]}, Regularization -> "Abel"]
```

gives **1/2**.

Comment: However, Table[NIntegrate[Exp[-x]*(1 - x/10^n)^(10^n), {x, 0, 10^n}], {n, 1, 
  4}] performs $\{0.487198,0.498747,0.499875,0.499987\} $, confirming $\frac 1 2$.

Comment: The limit exists or does not exist. The statement "the limit is NOT convergent! " is your invention.

Comment: This was a nice idea!  How do you justify changing the order of integration and summation?

Comment: @mjw Rigorously speaking, I am not. However, as the terms are integrable and bounded, I think the interchange should be fine (in the spirit of Fubini's theorem, considering the sum as another integral). In my opinion, the real issue is when I take the limit inside the sum: this may be too far.

Comment: Also, relying on regularization to evaluate a limit does not exist may not be a convincing argument.